# Regex with PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I cannot understand where i am going wrong.

Simple Form.

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return(validate());">
  <fieldset>
    <label for="phone">Phone Number </label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" size="30"><br><div id="badphone" style="background-color: #A9A9F5;"></div>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<script>
function validate()
{
    var pattern2=new RegExp("[/^[(]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[)]{0,1}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{4}$/]");
    if(document.myForm.phone.value.match(pattern2))
    {
    var badphone = "<strong>Phone Number can only contain Numbers 0-9</strong>";
    document.getElementById("badphone").innerHTML = badphone;
    document.myForm.phone.focus() ;
    return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

I have tried a couple other Regex's to get this to work but no luck.

I am tring to get an output like:

```
1112223333, 111-222-3333, (111)222-3333, 111 222 3333, 111.222.3333
```

Currently it is not validating at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax of using regex using `RegExp` constructor is wrong.

Your regex can be simplified to:

```
var pattern2 = /^\(?\d{3}\)?[-\s.]?\d{3}[-\s.]?\d{4}$/;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. After testing this it would not allow any combo of numbers however it would allow letters. How do i fix "document.myForm.phone.value.match(pattern2)" not match?

Comment: Are you sure this regex is allowing letters? Can you provide a jsfiddle demo?

Comment: Also i have another regex that works fine so im not sure where i am using the RegExp constructor wrrong "var pattern1=new RegExp("[^a-z|^A-Z|^ ]");" check for special or numbers in string

Comment: Using `RegExp` object it would be: **`var pattern2 = new RegExp("^\\(?\\d{3}\\)?[-\\s.]?\\d{3}[-\\s.]?\\d{4}$");`**

Comment: Did you check the demo link I provided?

Comment: I did created a line "var pattern2=new RegExp("^\(?\d{3}\)?[-\s.]?\d{3}[-\s.]?\d{4}$");" now it will allow anything through

Comment: Are you sure you're reading my comments? Did you check the demo link I provided above?

Comment: Yes i think im reading the comments i hate RegEx chenged line to "var pattern2=new RegExp("/^\(?\d{3}\)?[-\s.]?\d{3}[-\s.]?\d{4}$/");" still no good

Comment: Forget all you're trying. **Did you check [this demo link](http://regex101.com/r/xJ3qN2/1)**

Comment: Yes i checked the Demo Link that is where  "var pattern2=new RegExp("/^(?\d{3})?[-\s.]?\d{3}[-\s.]?\d{4}$/");" and "var pattern2=new RegExp("^(?\d{3})?[-\s.]?\d{3}[-\s.]?\d{4}$");" came from

Comment: It has to be `var pattern2 = /^\(?\d{3}\)?[-\s.]?\d{3}[-\s.]?\d{4}$/;` without using `RegExp`. Anyway can you show in my demo link where it is accepting any letters?

Comment: Want to give credit to Anthony Fornito for answering the how to say not match.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the `[/` and `/]` at the start and ending of the RegEx?

Try removing it.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I don't have 50 reputation to comment the question :(

Comment: i think now you could :-)

Comment: Tried that as well same result would not allow any combo of numbers however it would allow letters.

Comment: This code: `var pattern2=new RegExp("^[(]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[)]{0,1}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{4}$");
console.log("1112223333".match(pattern2));`
Executed on browser's console returns `true`. You'r code are checking if the phone IS right and then showing the error message. Try implementing @AnthonyFornito 's answer too: you need a `!` after the IF keyword.

Answer (score 0):

If want to say not in JS try this

```
if(!document.myForm.phone.value.match(pattern2))
```

If the what you have is doing the opposite of what you want change the operator.